Which partner (if either) should overcall 2NT (and why)?
With no one vulnerable at matchpoints, my right hand opponent opened two spades (weak).
I passed with the following hand: ♠T ♥A74 ♦JT92 ♣KT763.
After the game, I said, "I was thinking of bidding 2NT (unusual), but I felt I needed a fifth diamond." An opponent said, "No, you were right to pass. The unusual 2NT applies only to one spade. Over two spades, 2NT shows a strong hand with a spade stopper.
Partner had ♠AQ97 ♥86 ♦KQ85 ♣A54, which sort of fits this bill. Is partner strong enough to bid 2NT with weak hearts and play there? (Two pairs did so and shared top scores.) And it was partner, not me, who should bid 2NT for reasons stated at the end of the last paragraph, right?

Yes, you are correct. Partner should bid 2NT, and frankly, you should raise to 3. Partner has essentially a minimum for the 2NT overcall, and you have good values and a source of tricks in the club suit. On anything other than a heart lead by the spade bidder, you are likely to make 3NT (and on a heart lead you are unlikely to make 2NT).

Given that partner is in balancing seat, they definitely have enough to bid 2N.  I would bid this in direct seat as well, but that's because the AQxx in opponent's suit is worth more than 6, and the hand has no uncovered queens and jacks - I would not automatically overcall 2N in direct seat on any balanced 15 with a stopper.
